# log4j2: parent logger level lower than child logger

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am not sure if this has been answered before. I saw cases with root but I am not sure if the same is applicable to my scenario as well. This is my sample log file. Consider Case 1:

```
<logger name="com.abc" level="warn" additivity="false">
  <appender-ref ref="Default"/>
</logger>
<logger name="com.abc.xyz" level="debug" additivity="false">
  <appender-ref ref="Default"/>
</logger>
<root level="error">
  <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
</root>
```

In the above case, the child package has a lower debug level than the parent. So when I run my application, I get the logs from the package "com.abc.xyz" with debug level and the rest of the application at warn level. However when the same is reversed, i.e. consider Case 2:

```
<logger name="com.abc" level="debug" additivity="false">
  <appender-ref ref="Default"/>
</logger>
<logger name="com.abc.xyz" level="warn" additivity="false">
  <appender-ref ref="Default"/>
</logger>
<root level="error">
  <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
</root>
```

In the above case, the child package logger level is not honored and all the logs from the package "com.abc" are logged at debug level.
Is there any configuration that can be used to ensure that the child package logger level is given more precedence over parent level?

Comment: In which case this makes sence?

Comment: @Jens in our application we have scenarios where we have classes at the level com.abc. These classes contain common code. And then there are classes at child level, com.abc.xyz which is more specific to functionality.

Comment: @Jens why? There is zero reason to refactor...

Answer (score 2):

Works for me.

The important bit is that the child logger must have `additivity="false"`, but you got that right.

There must be something more to your issue, something else is causing this. Either you're not correctly matching the loggers, or there's more configuration than you show that overrides the part shown.

Comment: Is there anything specific that you are looking for? I could share the log4j2.xml for review.

Comment: Start by just keeping the two loggers and the appender as posted in your application, and see if that still behaves wrong. If it does not, the problem is elsewhere in the config.